# Cannot install vlc-plugin-libde265 to play H.265 (mkv/mp4) videos properly

Tags: xubuntu, vlc, hevc

As I found out, I need to install `vlc-plugin-libde265` in order to play H.265 videos properly. After adding generally recommended PPA below, I still cannot find the package:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:strukturag/libde265 
$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-libde265
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package vlc-plugin-libde265
```

- Xubuntu 16.04.03 (xenial)
- The content of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/strukturag-ubuntu-libde265-xenial.list`:

  ```
  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu xenial main
  deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu xenial main
  ```

What PPA do I have to use?

Comment: You have mixed H.264 and H.265 together in your question, my suspicion is that you mean '265' each time?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I meant 265 HEVC.

Comment: There is no need for libde265 in 16.04 to decode h.265(hevc) video, it's handled with 16.04's ffmpeg shared libs. Any player should have no issue per se with hevc so your problem is either the files themselves or so other localized issue. Can you play a sample from here?  (try the small one at top, i.e. jellyfish-3-mbps-hd-hevc.mkv) http://jell.yfish.us/  Try it in vlc & totem, ect.

Comment: Well, this is weird. Videos I couldn't play yesterday via VLC (Parole worked) I can now play in VLC as well. Without no intervention. I can play both samples (H.264/265).

Answer (score 0):

The next works for me in ubuntu 14.04.Try this:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-libde265

The above 
"sudo add-apt-repository ppa:strukturag/libde265" and

"sudo apt-get update" works for me for totem, not vlc, if i next to it do this:

"sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-libde265" and "sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-libde265".

I wish it work for you.Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 and possibly prior as well gets its 265 from  `sudo apt-get install libde265-0`